# Why fails to assign value to attribute in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm doing the last exercise in chap 13 of the book "Agile Web Development with Rails".

Previously there was a model named "Order" and I created a migration to add a column named "ship_date":

```
add_column :orders, :ship_date, :datetime
```

Then I added a line in "create" action in the orders_controller before respond_to like this:

```
@order.ship_date = Time.now.to_date
```

Then I modified the test file like this:

```
ship_date_expected = Time.now.to_date  ### new line
post_via_redirect "/orders",
                  order: { name:     "Dave Thomas",
                           address:  "123 The Street",
                           email:    "dave@example.com",
                           pay_type: "Check",
                           ship_date: Time.now.to_date } ### new line
### some existing lines
assert_equal ship_date_expected, order.ship_date  ### new line
```

Then I run the integration test but get failures like this:

```
test_buying_a_product(UserStoriesTest)[H:/Sites/rails_projects/depot/test/integration/user_stories_test.rb:56]:<Tue, 22 Jan 2013> expected but was <nil>.
```

I checked the database and was sure the new column exists. So I guessed the problem is about the assignment. This should be a dumb problem ... but I don't know how to fix it. Could anyone help me?

ThX!!!

The create action:

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
  @order.add_line_items_from_cart(current_cart)
  @order.ship_date = Time.now.to_date

  respond_to do |format|
    if @order.save
      Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
      session[:cart_id] = nil
      OrderNotifier.received(@order).deliver
      format.html { redirect_to store_url, notice: I18n.t('.thanks') }
      format.json { render json: @order, status: :created, location: @order }
    else
      @cart = current_cart
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Note this test could fail in pathological cases running over midnight; IMO it'd be better to create a variable to hold the results so it isn't called twice.

Answer (score 1):

Remember you need to `save` your `@order` after making the assignment!

Comment: Yes, I have saved it using `if @order.save` in the respond_to in the create action. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Fair enough. Perhaps you could post some more of your create action?

Comment: I added the create action in the post.

Comment: @colinxt - Hmm. Nothing obviously wrong. This is a complete shot in the dark, but you're storing a `Date` in a `:datetime` field. Does it work if you set `@order.ship_date = Time.now`, or if you make the database column a `:date`?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I'll try to find out the answer on my own. Should be a silly mistake. Thanks anyway~

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, It's because i forgot to  update **order_params**.
You need to grant the permission to **:ship_date**, Otherwise the date value won't be able to save in the ship_date column. That's also the reason why you get **nil**

```
 def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:name, :address, :email, :pay_type, :ship_date)
```